# By clicking p:commandButton 5 times the page restarts and calls PostConstruct

Tags: jsf, iframe, primefaces

I am working with JSF - PrimeFaces 3.5 anda java 7.

On the screen I have buttons that when clicked will open a PDF inside an iframe, and it is working, but by clicking 5 times the button that shows the PDF the page is restarted, ie it calls the "@PostConstruct" again and restarts the page. This always happens in the 5th click of the button, I've tried with link too.

The buttons that show the pdf are inside a dataTable, I removed everything from the page to do some tests and the clean html only with the buttons and the iframe was like this:

```
<h:form>        
    <p:panel id="panel1">
        <p:commandButton 
            id="btn1"
            icon="ui-icon-document" 
            value="BTN1"  
            action="#{bean.setFile(34189)}"
            oncomplete="refreshPdf()" />    
    
        <p:commandButton 
            id="btn2"
            icon="ui-icon-document" 
            value="BTN2"  
            action="#{bean.setFile(34190)}"
            oncomplete="refreshPdf()" />
    </p:panel>
    
    <p:remoteCommand name="refreshPdf" update="pdfs"/>
    
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:panel id="pdfs">
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 90%; overflow-y: hidden;">
                    <iframe
                            width="100%" 
                            height="890px" 
                            frameborder="0"  
                            marginwidth="0" 
                            marginheight="0" 
                            src="#{bean.getUrlPage(request.contextPath)}"></iframe>
                </div>
           </p:panel>
        </h:panelGroup>     
    </h:form>
```

The bean looked like this:

```
@Inject
private FileService              fileService;
private File                     fileSelected;
private String                   page;

@PostConstruct
private void initComponents() {
    // Init components
}

public void setFile(Integer id) {
    this.fileSelected = this.fileService.getById(id);
}


public String getUrlPage(String contextPath) {
    
    if (this.fileSelected != null) {
        this.page= contextPath+ "/app/cadastro/process/pdf?cod="+this.fileSelected.getId();            
    }
    return page;
}
```

The page that is called in the url to generate the PDF is as follows:

```
public void getPdf(Integer codFile) throws IOException {
   
   if (codFile!= null) {
       byte[] bytesArquivo = this.fileService.download(codFile);
       FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
       HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

       response.reset();
       response.setContentType("application/pdf");
       response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"name.pdf\"");

       OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
       output.write(bytesArquivo);
       output.close();

       facesContext.responseComplete();
   }
```

}

I've tried updating the entire page, the form, I've already removed ajax from the button, I updated the panel with javaScript, as I commented I took everything off the screen, this example is as simple as possible code, but always when clicking 5 times the button PostConstruct is called ... Do you know what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I'll show you what I did here.

Try this here, create the following document below, then go to web.xml and replace the file "base-spring-mvc.xml" with the document that was created.

Here below is the web.xml change

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:/base-spring-mvc.xml</param-value>  //REMOVE THIS LINE
  <param-value>classpath*:/YOUR-NEW-FILE-mvc.xml</param-value> // ADD YOUR NEW FILE HERE
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Below is the new file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config" 
xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"   
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd ">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ GENERAL CONFIG ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
        
<context:component-scan base-package="caesb" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<alias name="messageSource" alias="msg" />  

<faces:resources /> 

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    
<mvc:annotation-driven />            

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" /> 
    
 <!-- Trata o viewName (vide UriViewHandler do websupport) gerado por SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter -->
<bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
    p:viewClass="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" 
    p:prefix="/view/" p:suffix=".xhtml" p:order="2"/>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
            
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ REST POR INTERFACE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    
<!-- Habilita controllers por interface (Actions) -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" p:order="2" 
    p:pathPrefix="rest" p:caseSensitive="true"/>
    
<!-- Trata o handler "Controller" gerado por mvc:view-controller ou ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping. -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

 <!-- Resolve os modelAndView gerados pelos controllers (Actions) -->
<bean id="contentNegotiatingViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"
    p:order="1">
    
    <!-- All configuration is now done by the manager - since Spring V3.2 -->
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
            <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/xml" />              
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                <map>
                    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json;charset=utf-8" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>        
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xmlView"/>
            <ref bean="jsonView"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" p:prefix="/app/rest/">
                <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView"
    p:contentType="application/xml" p:marshaller-ref="xmlMarshaller" />
            
<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView"
    p:contentType="application/json" p:marshaller-ref="jsonMarshaller" />
 
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ WEBFLOW INTEGRATION ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->           

<!-- Mapeia no spring as URLs de fluxos -->
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping" p:order="3" p:flowRegistry-ref="flowRegistry" />

<!-- Trata o handler "FlowHandler" gerado por FlowHandlerMapping. -->
<bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter" p:flowExecutor-ref="flowExecutor"  />
        
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ WEBFLOW  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    
<!-- max-execution-snapshots="0" desativa serialização (que é feita 1 ou 2 vezes por request) -->
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" >
    <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="-1" max-execution-snapshots="0" />
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener" />
        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>        
        <webflow:listener ref="primeRenderListener" />
        <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/view">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/flow.xml" />
    <webflow:flow-location id="parent-flow" path="parent-flow.xml"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>

<faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" development="true" />

<bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>
<bean id="primeRenderListener" class="caesb.websupport.web.webflow.PrimeRenderFragmentsListener"/>

<bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener" 
    class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener">
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
</bean>     

</beans>
```

Comment: This answer seems to be completely out of context. How did you know that OP is using Spring?

Comment: @BalusC So actually I do not know lol, but I had exactly the same problem, it may be that it helps in something, or even for it to start a search for a solution based on the problem I had.